# What regular Expression match all international Mobile numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to validate mobile number field. I have tried many regular expression based on my requirement

Matching cases

1. (923)(423)(34455)
2. 945 443 4442
3. 919774744323
4. +92 332 45 666
5. 9144565
6. 91-877-3655

I need a regular expression based on my matching cases.

Comment: Does the numbers need to be valid? For example: If there is a wrong prefix number, should it match if the format is correct? (for example `+999 99 999`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
^[+]?(?:\d+|(?:\(\d+\)){3,}|\d+(?:(?: +|-)\d+){2,})$
```

You have a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Yjl0OK/5/)

Explained:

```
^    # begin of line
    [+]?  # optinally start by +
    (?:   # group of possible options
        \d+ |         # first option: all numbers
        (?:\(\d+\)){3,} |    # second option: group of numbers withn parenthesis (min=3)
        \d+(?:(?: +|-)\d+){2,}  # third option: group of numbers separated by spaces or dash (min=3)
    )     # end of group of options
$    # end of line
```